# Using jquery.easytabs with bootstrap 3 navbar-toggle issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use easytabs jquery with Twitter Bootstrap 3. The problem is when i try to resize it, the navbar-toggle isn't working anymore when I click it, nothing appears. Any idea why?

Here is what my html structure looks like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <h1><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bach Wigs</a></h1>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="tabContainer">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class='active'><a href="#salon">Salon</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#services" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#hairCare">Hair Care</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#hairExtensions">Hair Extensions</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#hairColor">Hair Color</a></li>
                            <!-- <li class="divider"></li> -->
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#location">Location</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>

                <section class="body">
                    <div id="salon">
                        <div class='salon-title center-block'>
                            <img src="img/LogoPNG2.png" alt="logo" class='center-block'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='salon-description center-block'>
                            <h3>Bach Wigs</h3>
                            <p>We provide top quality in all our services color, cut, style, extensions, wigs and much more.</p>
                            <p> Our newly remodeled salon established, December, 2012 services the finest clientele in the Metroplex, the United States and several countries around the world.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="services">
                        <div class='salon-title center-block'>
                            <img src="img/LogoPNG2.png" alt="logo" class='center-block'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='salon-description center-block'>
                            <h3>Bach Wigs</h3>
                            <p>We provide top quality in all our services color, cut, style, extensions, wigs and much more.</p>
                            <p> Our newly remodeled salon established, December, 2012 services the finest clientele in the Metroplex, the United States and several countries around the world.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

And here's the javascript code when i try to use easytabs:

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
            $('#tabContainer').easytabs({
                transitionIn: 'fadeIn',
                transitionOut: 'fadeOut',
                animationSpeed: 'slow'
            });
        });
```

**UPDATE:**
I changed `tabContainer` back to `bs-example-navbar-collapse-1` and created another div to place the tab id for easytabs jquery to function. Problem now is the body contents are also getting hidden when going responsive. I know it's because of the order, I'm finding ways how to solve this. Hopefully you can give out some ideas too. Thanks!

If you want, you can take a look at the website itself. http://webguy.moe/hair

Comment: would you show nav parent...? may be it's because of parents?
But with my browser navbar-toggle works fine...!!! I'm using chrome 37

Comment: That's weird, I tried it on mozilla and chrome and it's not working!! haha

Comment: ?????
Cool... but it's OK in mine...

Comment: navbar toggle does appear, but when you click it nothing shows up.

Comment: Update, got it working. only a few issues remain standing

Comment: actually I even test it's toggle collapse on click and every thing is OK...
FireFox  32--->`OK`... but your site won't come up in Explorer 11!!! It just show your footer, means just your phone number...
I think you have to make a fiddle or copy your whole code here...